# Creating Microsoft Word page template with table

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

[image: [sketch](http://i.imgur.com/euwkhPN.jpg)]

I need to prepare a document with the format above. Dynamic parts are page number, date title, etc. I know a similar thing is possible with headers and footers but couldn't find a way to do this template with a table.

I tried to prepare a page formatted like this once and just duplicate for new pages but the text flow becomes an issue. When I edit one of the pages, it expands or shrinks to other pages carrying their table borders as expected. This process is cumbersome and requires me to manually edit every page to fix text shift.

Is there a way to achieve this in Microsoft Word?

**Edit:**
I have a messy fix now, created tables for header and footer with no borders then added a rectangle from drawing panel as page border. The border rectangle encloses full page and it carries on because it is placed in the header. I had to manually try and set table sizes to fit outer border because apparently setting width to %100 leaves small uneven gaps on the sides.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the first two rows of the table as heading rows in each page, but I don't have a solution for your "table footer"

Comment: Here is a workaround for table footers http://word.tips.net/T000415_Repeating_Rows_for_a_Table_Footer.html